# Multiple iTunes audiobook downloads

Tags: itunes, download

I bought an audiobook on iTunes on my computer. Can I, using the same account, download the file onto my phone, via the iTunes app, without being charged again? Or do I have to sync? I'm afraid to try it, because I know if I am charged, Apple won't give me a re-fund, even though I've already purchased the book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can put the file onto your iPhone via iTunes without being charged a second time.

Comment: I just tried to download it, and it said "You have already purchased this item. Would you like to buy it again?"

Comment: So the item is not in your iTunes library? If you've already purchased and downloaded it, it should be on your computer so that you can transfer it to your device.

Comment: I'm not trying to sync it. I'm trying to download it via the iTunes app on the phone. I'm sure I can sync it.

Comment: You will be charged if you buy it again.